# Vuejs v-dialog takes last element in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

> vuejs

I want to iterate a posts array with dialog, but the last post in the
array appears

...................................................

```
 <v-card v-if="openPostNotification">
       <v-list-item v-for="post in postNotificationArr" :key="post.data.post._id">
         <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>
           <v-dialog
          v-model="dialog2"
          width="500"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              color="red lighten-2"
              dark
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
              Click Me
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <notify-post
            :image="'http://localhost:3000/static/' + post.data.post._id + '.PNG'"
            :name="post.data.post.text"
            :id="post.data.post._id"
            :commentsArr="post.data.post.comments"
            :likeNumber="post.data.post.likes.length"
            :likesArr="post.data.post.likes"
            :owner="post.data.post.owner"
            :ownerName="post.data.post.owner.name">
            </notify-post>
          
        </v-dialog>
      </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-card>
```

Comment: you are not implementing it the right way You should just add the dialog out of the loop and pass the value on click of specific item that way it will show your specific value

Comment: how should be.?